# IDA Pro Update String References

Tags: reverse-engineering, ida

I am currently trying to shift a string into an empty memory address and then update it's old reference. It is clear to me how to move the string into a space with enough 00 bytes, but I am unsure how to update its reference (so "aSup" points to the new memory address rather than the old one, which has been replaced with something else).
[image: Image One][image: Image 2]

In the above, I am trying to change "sup" to a longer string. My plan was to move the longer string into the sequence of 00 bytes under it, and then update the aSup reference to point to that new, longer string. However, I am unsure of how to update the reference as I do not see any edit functionality in IDA Pro to accomplish this.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: check out [reverseengineering.SE](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/)